# how to check different value in toBe method

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine

I am writing a test to check if all the links have the right text. 
but i need to check for two values, it can be "enable" or "disable"

```
expect(toggleName).toBe('Disable');
```

how can i check for 2 or more values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [custom matcher](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html).

You can find the following example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/R8XZu/):

```
describe('Custom matcher', function () {
    var customMatchers = {
        toBeThisOrThat: function (util, customEqualityTesters) {
            return {
                compare: function (actual) {
                    var result = {};
                    result.pass = util.equals(actual, "This", customEqualityTesters) || util.equals(actual, "That", customEqualityTesters);
                    if (result.pass) {
                        result.message = "Expected " + actual + " not to be this or that";
                    } else {
                        result.message = "Expected " + actual + " to be this or that";
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    beforeEach(function () {
        jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);
    });

    it("should equal this or that", function () {
        expect('This').toBeThisOrThat();
        expect('That').toBeThisOrThat();
        expect('foo').not.toBeThisOrThat();
    });
})
```